# HEC HMS 4.10 Error 20656 Missing or negative precipitation values

Tags: model, modeling

I am trying to run my continuous simulation using HEC HMS and I have data entered for my precipitation gages. There are no negative values or missing values however I get the error "Error 20656: Hyetograph gage 1 for subbasin contains 24 missing or negative precipitation values." I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix ... under meteorological model, set replace missing to "set to default"

Answer (score 0):

check control start - end date with gage dates they have to be similar